# SAPUI5 : How to update display on SelectedKey change?

Tags: sapui5, html-select

I have problem with display information.
I need to set the values from the [Drop box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBftT.png)

Code from `clothing.json`

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "clothing": {
      "categories": [
        {"name": "Women", "categories": [
          {"name":"Clothing", "categories": [
            {"name": "Dresses", "categories": [
              {"name": "Casual Red Dress", "amount": 16.99, "currency": "EUR", "size": "S"},
              {"name": "Short Black Dress", "amount": 47.99, "currency": "EUR", "size": "M"},
              {"name": "Long Blue Dinner Dress", "amount": 103.99, "currency": "USD", "size": "L"}
            ]},
```

Code from `View.xml`

```
<Column id="colSize" width="11rem">
  <m:Label text="Size"/>
  <template>
     <m:Select
        id = "selSize"
        selectedKey="{size}"
        items="{path: '/sizes', templateShareable: true}"
        visible="{= !!${size}}"
        forceSelection="false">
        <core:Item key="{key}" text="{value}"/>
      </m:Select>
   </template>
 </Column>
```

and part the code from `Controller.js`

```
    onPressBtnSetSize: function() {
        var oComboBox = this.byId("cbxSelectSize"),
            sKey = oComboBox.getSelectedItem().getKey(),
            oSelect = this.byId("selSize");
            oSelect.setSelectedKey(sKey);       
    }
```

Now, when I call the method `getSelectedKey()`. I get the meaning of my `sKey`.
But the display in the table does not change.

I think you need to update or refresh the table. But all my attempts failed. Kindly help!

Comment: How about `this.getView().getModel().setProperty("size", sKey)`. Then every Select with a binding of `selectedKey="{size}"` should be updated.

Comment: I tried it:  
`this.getView().getModel().setProperty("size", sKey);
this.getView().getModel().refresh(true);`  
as well as two methods (attachPropertyChange() and attachRequestCompleted()) from the class sap.ui.model.Model  
unsuccessfully.  
Or I'm doing something wrong, or need another way. @Marc

Answer (score -1):

```
    id = "selSize"
    ...
    var oComboBox = this.byId("cbxSelectSize"),
```

?